# script no entra en en condicional

Tags: php, javascript, script

formulario

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="remito">REMITO</label>
      <input type="float" name="remito" id="remito" 
         class="form-control" placeholder="*Remito..."></input> 
      </div>
   </div> 
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pagado">PAGADO</label>
      <input type="float" disabled name="pagado" id="pagado" 
         readonly="true" class="form-control" 
           placeholder="PAGADO..">
       </div>
   </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="disponible">DISPONIBLE</label>
       <input type="float" disabled name="disponible" 
          id="disponible"
           class="form-control" placeholder="*DISPONIBLE.." >
       </div>
      </div>
```

tengo las siguientes variables

```
remito=$("#remito").val();//valor 5
disponible=$("#disponible").val();//valor 500,00
pagado=$("#pagado").val();//valor 1000,00
```

Este funcional perfecto

```
 if(pagado == 0){
  $("#guardar").show();    
}
```

luego trato de hacer este condicional

```
  if(pagado !=0  && remito > disponible){

    alert ("Error: 1.La cantidad ingresada es mayor al Stock disponible");
    $("#guardar").hide();
   }
```

si pueden ver los valores no debería entrar en el alert (los valores los imprimí en el console.log) pero entra me podrían ayudar a ver que estoy haciendo mal? gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar, saludos

Comment: Pues de acuerdo con tu propia redacción y código (*el cual repliqué*) no se ejecuta el alert por que una de las 2 condiciones no se cumple, la de *mayor que*, ¿podrías revisar tu código de nuevo y/o exlicar mejor?

Comment: en mi caso entra en el alert, eso es lo que no se?por eso pido ayuda voy a editar mejor a ver si logras ver algo que no estoy viendo

Comment: Listo lo edite a ver si pueden ver algo que yo no veo, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ya vi el error lo que pasa es que remito más abajo lo trato como un arreglo entonces tenia que sumar ese arreglo para que no entrata en la condición evaluara bien

Comment: Probando con los valores que dices escritos a mano no entra en el `if`.

Comment: agrega la primera parte de la condicional asi  `pagado !== 0`, no creo que solucione tu problema, pero para evitar bugs

Comment: gracias pero si lo hago !==0, no entra en el condicional, ya entró el tema es que si elimino las cantidades malas luego de recibir el alert sigue entrando en el condicional es decir; solo lo hace bien si actualizo el formulario